# String manupilation

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

Here I am reading a string by opening my database and then trying to plot a graph based on that.I will really appreciate if anyone could help me solve this.Thanks
Method from MyDatabase which I am reading;

```
public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_SYSTOLIC,KEY_DIASTOLIC,KEY_PULSE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result =" ";


    int iSys = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SYSTOLIC);


    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){

        result = result + c.getString(iSys) + ",";

    }

    return result;
```

// The string from the database looks like "1,2,3,4,5";

```
MyDatabase myDb = new MyDatabase(this);
             myDb.open();
             String pull = myDb.getData();
             pull = pull.substring(0, pull.length() - 1);
             myDb.close();

            String test = '"' + pull +  '"';
            String[] items = test.split(",");

            int[] results = new int[items.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                try {
                    results[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);

                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {};
            }

// doesn't plots a graph on int[] results.             


              int[] yAxis = new int[]{11,12,13};

                TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("X-Axis");
                for(int s=0; s< results.length; s++){

                    series.add(results[s], yAxis[s]);

            }

                XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
                dataset.addSeries(series);

                XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
                XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
                mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

                 LinearLayout chart_container=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Chart_layout);

                mChart=(GraphicalView)ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, mRenderer);
                chart_container.addView(mChart);

            }
```

Comment: can you post your error report?

Comment: Try adding a System.out.println("series.add("+results[s]+"," yAxis[s]+" - s="+s) inside the timeseries loop to see if series are added or not. Any exception raised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable i is not available outside the for loop.

You could declare a variable `i` before the `for` loop and use it, but it would not help you in this case.

If you want to populate the arr[], try this:

```
String[] items = test.split(",");
int[] arr = new int[items.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    try {
       arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
         } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {};
  }
```

Comment: I need to plot a graph and the values are not being passed.I used int[] arr = new int[items.length]; but when I try to access it like  int[] yAxis = new int[]{11,12,13};
     
     TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("X-Axis");
     for(int s=0; s< arr.length; s++){
     
      series.add(arr[s], yAxis[s]); The values are not passed.

Comment: @user3339618: Then publish the full code (full question) in the main question above

Comment: and I am using achartengine

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access `i` outside the `for` loop. It's not related to `try`/`catch`

As a work around you can define `i` before the loop